# Generated by global sections vs generated in degree zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ and consider the graded $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$-module $M=\bigoplus_{j \geq 0}\textrm{H}^0(\mathbb{P}_k^n, \mathcal{F}(j))$ ($k$ is a field). Can you give me an example where $\mathcal{F}$ is generated by its global sections, but $M$ is not generated in degree $0$?

Comment: By $\mathcal{F}(j)$ in the sum for $M$ do you mean global sections of $\mathcal{F}(j)$?

Comment: yes, sorry I will fix this